# Delete history in local repository

Tags: git

Our repository has many frequent commits with binary files. New users clone the repo with "--depth 1" option, and the size is manageable at first. Over time, with frequent pulls, the size of the repo grows rapidly. Is there a way to clean up the local repo, so that only N last commits are remaining?

We don't want to delete those files from history in remote, just clean the history of the local repo to "--depth 1"

PS: I know, git is not designed for binary files, and we should use something like LFS, but LFS is not very stable yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)

Comment: Slava, once we delete .git what's the right way to re-initialize the repo from the correct commit, without cloning it?

Comment: Everton, this is a diff question. I made an edit to clarify it.